# Is this a bug in the tour of this site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I recently went on the tour of the site again, for no real reason, and I found that the example question was ['Is an olive tree frost resistant?'](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/is-an-olive-tree-frost-resistant). My answer to that question has five votes, townseans answer has six and is accepted. In the tour, though, my answer was shown as accepted and with a much higher vote count. Is this a bug, or are the numbers arbitrary in that example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to /tour on any Stack Exchange site, you'll see the same thing: a sample question with a score of +14 and two answers with a score of +3, with an animation where the bottom one gets another upvote and the accept mark, and switches places with the other one.

So it's not a bug, it's just the way that the graphics on the tour page are put together.

Comment: Also, under 'Improve posts by editing or commenting', it shows the accepted answer with a score of +8, if my memory holds.